# Android scrollview scrolls to edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a horizontal `ScrollView` which has `EditText`s on the most left, some other stuff in the middle, and on the right most I have a `Button`. When this button is clicked, a dialog appears. This dialog contains `EditText`. So when I open this dialog the edittext inside gains focus and the keyboard is shown. That's OK. But what is not OK is that the scroll view is scrolled to the edittext and that edit text gains focus.

So before I click the button the scroolview is scrolled all the way to the right and the focus is at the root `RelativeLayout` that contains the scrollview. That means no edittext has focus. But when I enter text in the dialog's edittext and press OK, the dialog is closed and now the scrollview is scrolled back all the way to the left and the edittext is focused.

How to prevent this to happen. I want the focus to stay on the `RelativeLayout` after the dialog is closed. I have set this on the `RelativeLayout` but it's the same:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: can you provide the layout and some code showing the behavior? It's difficult to understand and explain (which is ok as it is a complex behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: You can control which element gets focus with the `android:nextFocusXXX` attributes. Especially the `attributes:nextFocusForward` look promissing.

EDIT: As your comment says, the focus has to be shifted after the Dialog dismissed. You can add a call to `view.requestFocus()` for the EditText you want to have focus. Add that call in the `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`.

Comment: I use this when to handle the click on the next button on the keyboard, but how is it connected to the dialog? The scrollview is scrolled when the dialog is shown, not when the dialog is closed. When the dialog opens I can see in the background the the scrollview is scrolled immediately.

Comment: Yes, I see that point. My (wild) guess was to add that attribute to the button and see if it actually scrolls to the right place after the dialog dismissed. In the meantime I got another idea with the dialog. Just adding that to my answer

Comment: I don't want to focus any edit text. I want the focus to stay where it is before showing the dialog, and also the scrollview position to stay where it is before showing the dialog.

Comment: Then call `requestFocus()` on the Button. This should keep the scrollview where it should be after the dialog dismissed. BUT when the dialog is shown, the scrollview most likely will still scroll to the left corner of your RelativeLayout. I'm not aware of a possibility to move a dialog to certain position in a Layout - other then faking the dialog as FrameLayout. I tried that once and it got horribly complex.